# How to apply AspectJ in GWT application for logging?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, aspectj

How to apply AspectJ in GWT application for logging ?

I read the following article.

Javadoc: [Annotation Type EnableAspectJAutoProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html)

The class on which I am applying AspectJ doesn't have an interface.

The article doesn't mention anything about the Jars to add and also is their any specific order of export to be followed ?

Comment: By GWT application, you mean client side, like in the browser? Because that's not possible.

Comment: No not client, Server Side. I know already that it is not possible for client side. I just need to know for server side.

Comment: link explanation, removed chatty text

Comment: Your link points to JavaDoc for an annotation class, not to an article. How about just reading the [Spring AOP manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)? Your question is way too broad.